# Open Source License and Copyright Text

Tags: open-source-software

If I receive an open source software (for instance, a SaaS application) which contains some open source libraries or packages that I am familiar with, but without the inclusion of the license text (as indicated by many OSS licenses), is my usage of this software illegal?

Comment: Do you mean 'use' by just running the software that you already installed onto your computer? Or do you mean 'use' by redistributing the open source software (but without including the required license text)?

Comment: For software-as-a-service, you should also consider the specific open source license. For example, if it's the AGPL license, there are additional requirements when you run the software and make it possible for someone else to use that software over a network. That requirement is a separate one from the requirement of including the license text.

Comment: I meant just running @Brandin